# Sentences that begin with "To think that;" are they impersonal?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, nonfinite-verbs, subject-drop

Sentences such as

> *To think that she did all that*
>
> *To think that Messi and Cristiano Rolando are both out of the World Cup*
>
> *To think that this could ever happen to me*

Are these *impersonal sentences* (i.e. the infinitives have no subject) or are these sentences that have *implicit* subjects (because it's understood that "to think" requires *someone* to do the "thinking")?

My instinct tells me that they have *implicit subjects*; however, I can't add the implied subject (for example, I can't say *For me to think that she did all that*, or at least it sounds odd to me). It seems that these sentences, as written, reject overt subjects; why is that, and does that make such sentences *impersonal*?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is certainly a missing subject if one considers as these as sentence relicts.  If one accepts lbf's reconstruction, 'It is really shocking/surprising [when one is obliged to think] that ...', the recoverable (or hypothetical) subject is one undergoing extraposition ('impersonal').

Answer (score 1):

**to think (that)**

> It is really shocking or surprising that (something is the case)

Or

**I shudder/dread to ˈthink (how, what, etc....) (informal, often humorous)**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+shudder+to+think) another idiom

> I am afraid to think or ask myself about something, because the
>   answer might be terrible or unpleasant

And yes, you can say :

> For me to think that she did all that ...

You second sample sentence named the subjects. Implicit subjects are not imperative. Context as usual is important.

This is what 'me thinks' is the sense of all this.